# Print Specific slice from string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, random, integer, user-input

Given the string below, what is the most efficient way to print just the "number" words .i.e. one, two, three, at the end of each of the strings in python?

TT001AKP0000X000100one
SS004AKP0000X000100two
PP05AST0000X00010three
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regex approach here:

```py
inp = ["TT001AKP0000X000100one", "SS004AKP0000X000100two", "PP05AST0000X00010three"]
nums = [re.sub(r'^.*\d+', '', x) for x in inp]
print(nums)  # ['one', 'two', 'three']
```